# Manage Display Field Label not changing

Tags: entities

In Content Types->Manage Display->Label, there is the options of Above, Inline and Hidden, except no matter which one I choose, the page shows all field labels as Above. 
I have "clear Caches", restarted Apache, I even created a new content type to check if it was just the one content type.

What can make the field's label not show "inline"? Where and how to get it back to normal?

Comment: Did you check the html source if there is changes after you updated the label in Manage Display?

Comment: Are you using any module to control the layout like Display Suite? Or any custom tpl?

Comment: Check that you are changing it in the correct display view - perhaps you are changing the teaser view or vice versa?

Comment: @Gulok --I am using Display Suite, but even when I uninstall DS it will not show inline.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me there is a clashing between the Drupal orders to the CSS.

It is either a clashing with the CSS or a bug (I also experience bugs with manage display in Drupal 8 but different than the one you describe).

Anyway to check if this is CSS related, just replace the theme with another and check then.